# Trying to create a table of odds for a craps game

Tags: r, statistics

```
### Play the game many times
win=0; tie=0; N=10^4
for(j in 1:N){
  points=sum(sample(1:6, 2, replace=T))
  if(points==7 | points==11){win=win+1
  x = paste("natural winner",points);
  } else if(points==2 | points==3 |  points==12){
     x = paste("natural loser",points);
  } else for(i in 1:20){
    newroll=sum(sample(1:6, 2, replace=T)) 
    if(newroll==points){win=win+1; 
    x = paste("points winner",points); 
    break 
    } else if(newroll==7){
       x = paste("points loser",points); 
      break} 
    if(i==20){tie=tie+1; 
    x = paste("20 Bullets Survivor",points);
    } # end if i==20
  } # end i loop
} # end j look
```

The code works fine, although I'm new to R and want to use the table function to see how many times each outcome happens, how many times is there a natural winner, or a natural loser, etc. Something like the example I have below for a dice roll.

Probability for numbers of 5 dice being rolled:

[image]

I have tried setting x to the outcome and then using the function table(x), although it only gives me the last result, but I am trying to get all the results summed up into the table.

Comment: Are you trying to save the values of `x` here? At the moment, it looks like you're just overwriting the value of `x` every time your for loop runs. You would need to store the values somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a vector `x` with the length set to the number of trials `N`. Then in your loop, you can set the vector value by index `j`. In the end, you can use `table` of your final `x` vector. Note that I tried not to change any other code you have except for mild formatting.

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
set.seed(42)

win=0; tie=0; N=10^4

x <- numeric(length = N)

for(j in 1:N){
  points=sum(sample(1:6, 2, replace=T))
  if(points==7 | points==11){
    win=win+1
    x[j] <- paste("natural winner",points)
  } else if(points==2 | points==3 |  points==12){
    x[j] <- paste("natural loser",points)
  } else for (i in 1:20){
    newroll=sum(sample(1:6, 2, replace=T)) 
    if(newroll==points){
      win=win+1; 
      x[j] <- paste("points winner",points) 
    break 
    } else if(newroll==7){
      x[j] <- paste("points loser",points) 
      break
    } 
    if(i==20){
      tie=tie+1; 
      x[j] = paste("20 Bullets Survivor",points)
    } 
  }
}

table(x)
```

**Output**

```
x
20 Bullets Survivor 10  20 Bullets Survivor 4  20 Bullets Survivor 5  20 Bullets Survivor 6  20 Bullets Survivor 8 
                     3                      2                      4                      1                      1 
 20 Bullets Survivor 9       natural loser 12        natural loser 2        natural loser 3      natural winner 11 
                     1                    262                    280                    562                    578 
      natural winner 7        points loser 10         points loser 4         points loser 5         points loser 6 
                  1616                    508                    592                    698                    781 
        points loser 8         points loser 9       points winner 10        points winner 4        points winner 5 
                   767                    673                    262                    295                    460 
       points winner 6        points winner 8        points winner 9 
                   650                    571                    433
```